# Changing textview's frame based on keyboard being visible or not

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using observer to find out if keyboard is hidden or not. Keyboard should automatically show up as soon as view loads, this should trigger observer which adjusts the view. When view loads, keyboard shows up but there is still part of the textview hidden behind the keyboard, as soon as you hide the keyboard and show it again it will correctly adjust size of textview.

In viewDidLoad i've add observer

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
```

My textview becomes first responder in viewDidAppear such as

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    noteTextView.becomeFirstResponder()

}
```

Finally the view gets adjusted

```
@objc func adjustForKeyboard(notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: noteTextView.window)

    if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
        noteTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    } else {
        noteTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height, right: 0)
    }

    noteTextView.scrollIndicatorInsets = noteTextView.contentInset

    let selectedRange = noteTextView.selectedRange
    noteTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(selectedRange)
}
```

How could i fix this so it will appear correctly the first time? Using latest release of xcode.

Before hiding keyboard

[image: Part of textview is behind keyboard]

After hiding the keyboard you can see that the textview was hidden behind it

[image: Textview in full size after hiding keyboard]

After showing the keyboard again textview's size is adjusted.

[image: Keyboard is shown 2nd time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You duplicate `keyboardDidHideNotification`

```
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
```

You need `keyboardWillShowNotification` also

```
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil) 
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//MARK:- View delegates
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardDidChange), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)

}

//TODO: When WE edit the textfields >> this method calls
@objc func keyboardDidChange(notification: Notification) {
    debugPrint(notification)
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue, let keyboardAnimation : Double = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double{
        print("UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame keyboardAnimation : \(keyboardAnimation)ms")
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardAnimation) {
               self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
        else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardAnimation) {
                self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
            }
        }
    }
}

//TODO: Removes the observation on view deinit
deinit{
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame)
}
```